# Abrir via API as configurações do APK

Tags: android, android-activity

Gostaria de saber como faço para o usuário cair na configurações do aplicativo(APK) via **API**, por exemplo, o **usuário** colocou a opção "Não pergunta novamente",nas permissões do aplicativo, e eu abrir um alertDialog que faça o usuário ir para os configurações do app permitir diretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o código abaixo para exibir um alert com a opção de ir para as configurações do APP

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreenActivity.this).create();
dialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.grant_permission_title));
dialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.grant_permission_message)));
dialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", SplashScreenActivity.this.getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
});
```